# How to delete ec2-snapshot that are 1 days older using a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, delete-file, snapshot

I want to delete snapshots of volumes using a batch script, snapshots which are created on previous day.

```
for /f "tokens=2 skip=%AWS_SNAPSHOT_KEEP%" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\snapshots.txt) do call ec2-delete-snapshot %%s
```

This is deleting all the snapshot and keeping only one snapshot because AWS_SNAPSHOT_KEEP=1.

Please help me out.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: How can i set the date parameter in a script to previous date??

Comment: show a few lines from snapshots.txt

Comment: `Forfiles` is able to delete files older than 1 day.

Comment: @MattWilliamson: `SNAPSHOT snap-2f808 vol-3d6b completed 2013-11-29T04:54:41+0000 100% 109037527 10 11-28-2013: Daily Backup for test_VPC (VolID:vol-35f6b InstID:i-e1c43d6)
SNAPSHOT snap-d2edf7ed vol-f66409a0 completed 2013-11-29T04:54:38+0000 100% 109030037527 10 11-28-2013: Daily Backup for Test_Machine (VolID:vol-f69a0 InstID:i-8111)`

Comment: @foxidrive: what is the syntax of 'forfiles'?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=forfiles+older+than <-- have a look there.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `robocopy`'s `/minage` and `/maxage` parameters to select the files. Code example:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('robocopy "%cd%" "%temp%" * /minage:1 /maxage:2 /l /np /fp /njh /njs /ndl /ns^|findstr /riv /c:"^$" /c:"\*EXTRA File"') do echo %%~a
```